# Get message manager of a tab? (Firefox Add-on SDK)

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, mozilla

It is a Firefox add-on SDK.

I want to load a frame script to a given browser tab (complying with e10s).

Currently I try to do this for every tab (just for testing), but message manager is undefined. Why?

```
var self = require("sdk/self");
var { setTimeout} = require ("sdk/timers");
var { viewFor } = require("sdk/view/core");

function myFunc() {
  var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");
  for (let tab of tabs) {
    console.log(tab.title);
    var xulTab = viewFor(tab);
    console.log(xulTab.messageManager);
    console.log(tab.messageManager);
  } 
}
```

Both `log` print out `undefined`

I need `messageManager` object in order to call `loadFrameScript` function afterwards. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Excellent question. This is e10s safe:

`var mm = xulTab.linkedBrowser.messageManager`

Then you can use it as normal such as: `mm.sendAsyncMessage(....)`

Comment: Thank you. It works. Could you direct to the documentation of where we would be able to find the answer to this question or similar ones? I've looked at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/tab but found no `linkedBrowser` there.